# Test Android app with server (laptop) having dynamic ip

Tags: java, android, jboss, dynamic-ip

i am trying to test my app which has to get connected to my machine for backend java webservices running on jboss server. i have configured my jboss server to enable outer network to access the backend services.

```
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:192.168.42.219}"/>
    </interface>
```

everything worked when i had static ip address `192.168.42.219` , but admin says the machine can only have dynamic ips, and no more static ips allocated. now i am stuck; is there way i can test my android app with the back end services which has dynamic ips

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Comment: you meant  <interface name="public">
            <any-ipv4-address/>
        </interface>

Comment: but i have to mention hostname or ip to access the backend rite